# Paragraphs overlapping with css grid

Tags: html, css, position, overlapping, paragraph

[image]I'm trying to build a biography page with plain of text and I want my text to fill all the white space. I want to use CSS GRID for this project, don't want to deal with floats. I will add an image to show you how I want to look and where is my problem, maybe someone will know the fix.
I didn't write in this HTML all the lines because it's a lot. But you can see in the image.

I know i used on 2 elements span on the same spot ,but i wanted to show you how i want my text to fill the white space.

Please feel free to show me another examples with methods to make the text fill all the white space.

```css
.bio-content {
  display: grid;
  margin-top: 10rem;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr;
  grid-template-rows: 3fr;
}

.bio-content .info-img {
  margin-left: 1.5rem;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}

.bio-content .biography,
.bio-content biography2 {
  margin-left: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 0rem;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
  border-left: none;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

.bio-content .biography {
  grid-column: 2/4;
  grid-row: 1/4;
}

.bio-content .biography2 {
  grid-column: 1/4;
  grid-row: 3/4;
}

.bio-content table {
  grid-row: 2/3;
  grid-column: 1/2;
}

/* G-CYR : I added bg to see white text */
body {background:gray;}
```

```html
<main id="bio">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="bio-content">
      <div class="info-img">
        <img src="/Core/img/bio.jpg" alt="">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>NAME:</td>
            <td>LAZAR ANGELOV</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>HEIGHT:</td>
            <td>6"0(180 CM)</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>WEIGHT:</td>
            <td>195 LBS(88 KG)</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>DATE OF BIRTH:</td>
            <td>SEPTEMBER 22ND, 1984</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>BIRTHPLACE:</td>
            <td>SOFIA,BULGARIA</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="biography">
        <h1>Biography</h1>
        <p>Before becoming a bodybuilder and a personal point guards of his class. At the age of 16 he bodies.</p>

        <p> He dedicated his life to bodybuilding and since Lazar dominates other bodybuilders with balanced physique and incredible definition.</p>

      </div>
      <div class="biography2">
        <p>
          <p>He owns some of the best abs in the world. As a personal trainer he has been able to transform the chance to receive everything needed for reaching the maximum physical potential without using steroids.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

EDIT EDIT I tried to remove the grid row and to define .biography2 grid-row:4/4; and doesn't seems to work how i want...Please have a look at the last image .It remains a white space below the image[image]

Comment: you have css for ".biography1" but there doesn't seem to be a class [used] with that name? Is that meant to be biography?

Comment: Yes.sorry i wrote wrong here but in my actual css is correct

Comment: make a [codepen](https://codepen.io/), its easier to see where the length is going wrong. Paste in some [placeholder text](https://lipsum.com/feed/html)

Comment: `.biography` and `.biography2` are both set to be spanning till row 4 ,and column 4 , thats why they overlap, you set it so ;)

Comment: @RachelGallen i edited the question and made a snippet from original code, you may use it to test issue and possibly  answer.

Comment: Are both spanning till row 4 because i don't know hoe to set them to filling all the white space

Comment: Thank you a lot for your effort G-Cyr!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case if you want to have text like that the only solution is to use floats.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove `grid-row` definition from both biography:

```css
.bio-content {
  display: grid;
  margin-top: 10rem;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr;
  grid-template-rows: 3fr;
}

.bio-content .info-img {
  margin-left: 1.5rem;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}

.bio-content .biography,
.bio-content biography2 {
  margin-left: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 0rem;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
  border-left: none;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

.bio-content .biography {
  grid-column: 2/4;
}

.bio-content .biography2 {
  grid-column: 1/4;
}

.bio-content table {
  grid-row: 2/3;
  grid-column: 1/2;
}

/* G-CYR : I added bg to see white text */
body {background:gray;}
```

```html
<main id="bio">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="bio-content">
      <div class="info-img">
        <img src="/Core/img/bio.jpg" alt="">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>NAME:</td>
            <td>LAZAR ANGELOV</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>HEIGHT:</td>
            <td>6"0(180 CM)</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>WEIGHT:</td>
            <td>195 LBS(88 KG)</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>DATE OF BIRTH:</td>
            <td>SEPTEMBER 22ND, 1984</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>BIRTHPLACE:</td>
            <td>SOFIA,BULGARIA</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="biography">
        <h1>Biography</h1>
        <p>Before becoming a bodybuilder and a personal point guards of his class. At the age of 16 he bodies.</p>

        <p> He dedicated his life to bodybuilding and since Lazar dominates other bodybuilders with balanced physique and incredible definition.</p>

      </div>
      <div class="biography2">
        <p>
          <p>He owns some of the best abs in the world. As a personal trainer he has been able to transform the chance to receive everything needed for reaching the maximum physical potential without using steroids.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

As G-cyr pointed out, both sections are set to span til row 4 in your code. The easiest way to resolve your issue would be to set the css of biography2 to grid-row:4/4 instead of 3/4. This way, your biography 2 paragraph would appear on the last row, and the rest in the first 3.

```css
.bio-content {
  display: grid;
  margin-top: 10rem;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr;
  grid-template-rows: 3fr;
}

.bio-content .info-img {
  margin-left: 1.5rem;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}

.bio-content .biography,
.bio-content .biography2 {
  margin-left: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 0rem;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
  border-left: none;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

.bio-content .biography {
  grid-column: 2/4;
  grid-row: 1/4;
}

.bio-content .biography2 {
  grid-column: 1/4;
  grid-row: 4/4;
}

.bio-content table {
  grid-row: 2/3;
  grid-column: 1/2;
}

/* G-CYR : I added bg to see white text */
body {background:gray;}
```

```html
<main id="bio">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="bio-content">
      <div class="info-img">
        <img src="/Core/img/bio.jpg" alt="">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>NAME:</td>
            <td>LAZAR ANGELOV</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>HEIGHT:</td>
            <td>6"0(180 CM)</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>WEIGHT:</td>
            <td>195 LBS(88 KG)</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>DATE OF BIRTH:</td>
            <td>SEPTEMBER 22ND, 1984</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>BIRTHPLACE:</td>
            <td>SOFIA,BULGARIA</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="biography">
        <h1>Biography</h1>
        <p>Before becoming a bodybuilder and a personal point guards of his class. At the age of 16 he bodies.</p>

        <p> He dedicated his life to bodybuilding and since Lazar dominates other bodybuilders with balanced physique and incredible definition.</p>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque tristique est enim, a hendrerit odio sagittis sit amet. Cras augue tortor, dignissim in imperdiet sit amet, lobortis eget orci. Fusce arcu dui, sollicitudin sit amet elementum vel, suscipit ut justo. Nulla quis pretium sem. Aenean ut nibh leo. Vivamus cursus nibh et augue elementum facilisis. Aenean tortor mauris, maximus vestibulum cursus quis, maximus at est. Nunc ultricies luctus mi elementum.
        </p>

      </div>
      <div class="biography2">
        <p>
          <p>He owns some of the best abs in the world. As a personal trainer he has been able to transform the chance to receive everything needed for reaching the maximum physical potential without using steroids.</p>
                  <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque tristique est enim, a hendrerit odio sagittis sit amet. Cras augue tortor, dignissim in imperdiet sit amet, lobortis eget orci. Fusce arcu dui, sollicitudin sit amet elementum vel, suscipit ut justo. Nulla quis pretium sem. Aenean ut nibh leo. Vivamus cursus nibh et augue elementum facilisis. Aenean tortor mauris, maximus vestibulum cursus quis, maximus at est. Nunc ultricies luctus mi elementum.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: p.s there are various properties for ['white-space'](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) you can use but getting the grid layout correct (or omitting the grid spec) will be key to maximising your text around the image. You could also have a look at ['shape-outside'](http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/okd0h3qy/) - but this is not using a grid